# Struct with pointer and char in c

Tags: c, pointers, struct, char

My code is working with integer's value, but when I tried to add the character value ,then I have error.

Here's my code:

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 
  3 struct _pointer{
  4 
  5     int x;
  6     int y;
  7     char Q[200];
  8 
  9 }address,*pointer;
 10 
 11 
 12 main()
 13 {
 14     pointer = &address;  // here we give the pointer the address.
 15     pointer->x = 10;    // here we give the pointer the value to   variable x.
 16     pointer->y = 30;   // here we give the pointer the value to variable y.
 17     (*pointer).Q = "BANGO!";

 18     printf("The x variable is %d\nThe y variable is %d\nTheText\n",pointer->    x,pointer->y,pointer->Q);
 19 
 20 }
 21
```

So where is my mistake ?

Thanks

Comment: What're u trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

copying a string is done by `strcpy(char *dst, const char *src)`

Copy the string like this

```
strcpy(pointer->Q,"BANGO!");
```

Comment: in C language strings (`char *` type) do not support copying with operator =.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing `pointer->Q` to `printf` but there is no `%s` in the format string.

And also you should copy string with `strcpy(pointer->Q, "mystring");`

Answer (score 1):

I can see a few errors, the most important one is that you can't assign to arrays in c, to set the contents of the array to those of the string you need to copy the contents, you can use `strcpy()` for that, in your case you need

```
 strcpy((*pointer).Q, "BANGO!");
```

also, the rest of your code doesn't seem to be a good Idea, I recommend this instead

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct MyStruct
{
    int x;
    int y;
    char Q[200]; 
};

int
main()
{
    struct MyStruct  instance;
    struct MyStruct *pointer;

    pointer = &instance;

    pointer->x = 10;    // here we give the pointer the value to   variable x.
    pointer->y = 30;   // here we give the pointer the value to variable y.

    /* copy the contents of "BANGO!" into the array Q */
    strcpy(pointer->Q, "BANGO!");

    printf("x = %d\ny = %d\nQ = %s\n", pointer->x, pointer->y, pointer->Q);
    /*                           ^ you need this for ---------------^ this */

    /* or even */
    printf("x = %d\ny = %d\nQ = %s\n", instance.x, instance.y, instance.Q);
    /* which will print the same, since you modified it through the pointer */
    return 0;
}
```

you should also note, that `main()` returns and `int`.

There is no good reason to use global variables in a general case, there are situations where they are **needed** or **useful**, but in general you should avoid them.

Comment: @pythonlover Just to illustrate how pointers work. Did you [know](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1):

To my mind, you didn't even try to compile your code.

First of all, you cannot just assign a string to `char[]` you need to use `strcpy(char *to, char *from);`.

Then, you have three arguments to `printf` but only two formatting `%`'s.

Correct way:

```
 printf("The x variable is %d\nThe y variable is %d\nTheText variable is %s\n",pointer->x,pointer->y,pointer->Q);
```

and

```
strcpy(pointer->Q,"Your text");
```

Comment: yea! , I think the error is in the  (*pointer).Q = "BANGO!"; .

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use

```
strlcpy(pointer->Q,"BANGO!",sizeof(pointer->Q));
```

which is less error prone and guarantees a null termination of your string.

Comment: `strlcpy` is not standard.

Comment: @iharob Yes you are right but no harm to using it right? Since it is safer

Comment: It's safer if it's available, which is not guaranteed since it's not standard.